# PHP IMAP - Do emails have to have a messageid?

Tags: php, imap, gmail-imap

I'm retrieving emails from Gmail using PHP and IMAP; however, some emails don't have a messageid.  Aren't all messages supposed to have a messageid?

I need a unique id for reference so i'm not sure how else to keep track of emails without it.

Am i doing something wrong?

For example here is an email header i get

```
 [date] => Sun, 06 Nov 2011 21:21:56 -0500
    [subject] => Daylight Saving Time?  Chili's Saving Time!
    [to] => -------@gmail.com
    [message_id] => 
    [from] => ChilisCorp@---.com
    [sender] => ChilisCorp@----.com
    [reply_toaddress] => ChilisCorpeclubsupport@---.com
    [size] => 14385
    [msgno] =>  156
    [status] => Unread
```

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any MTA I have ever encountered will add a Message-ID if one is not already present.  However, if you need to keep track of messages or thread them, you will need to set a the `Message-ID`. The `References` header and the `In-Reply-To` header use the value of a previous `Message-ID` to relate messages together.

`References` contains a list of previous `Message-ID` values in the reply chain, and `In-Reply-To` contains the `Message-ID` to which the current message is a direct reply.

Note that according to the RFC-2822 specification, [a Message-ID is technically not required](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.6.4). Well-behaved MTAs generally include one, but some commenters below describe instances where a Message ID was not present, causing failures in messaging clients.

Comment: But since there's nothing guaranteeing it, this doesn't stop a buggy/malicious MTA from using identical Message-IDs for different mails right? What's the best way to guard against this situation?

Comment: @Pacerier if your concern is making sure another MTA can't replicate your server's Message-ID, that is difficult. You could create the message ID as a hash of the message time, your hostname, and a secret key, which would make it hard to forge a Message-ID but I'm not sure you gain much.  The only strong method of sender verification in email is PGP signing and encryption.

Comment: An update to this old question: I have always believed a message ID is a "must" -- but I just discovered an email in my IMAP inbox that does not have one! I looked at the raw source. My IMAP-message reading software crashed because of this, like me it assumed there always is a Message ID.

Comment: I also just discovered an email without a message_id too - it is obviously a spam email and doesn't show up in my webmail client... but it does when I log in through imap.

Comment: @Simeon RFC-2822 does indeed say _though optional, every message SHOULD have a message ID_ https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.6.4

Answer (score 7):

The message ID has nothing to do with IMAP but is part of the mail itself and specified in [RFC 2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html) as "optional" (although it says that it should be present):

> Though optional, every message SHOULD have a "Message-ID:" field.

So you are not doing anything wrong if some mails lack a Message-ID. It happens for all the mails that the MUA that originally sent the mail did not generate one for (which however every commonly used MUA should do).

Concerning a unique ID for identifying mails via IMAP, you may want to have a look at the UID field described [in the standard](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3501.html).